# Background Location Fetch - Android

Tags: android, location, background-service

I am trying to make an android feature which starts a background service when app is sent to background. The background service have to fetch the latest user's location using GPS and send it to server while the app is in background, and it has to keep doing it until app is killed or app is brought to foreground.

I have tried many examples but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me in this regards
Would really appreciate

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Android has limit the background Service and Location from Android 8.0, can be read from below links.

[Service Limitation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

[Location Limitation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)